# Postgres `connection timed out` after connection with pooler

Tags: postgresql

Looking for any feedback about what to look at as far as debugging is concerned to address a "connection timed out" error with postgres in a newly developed go application.

`` failed to connect to `host=XX user=worker database=XX_v2`: dial error (dial tcp XX:5432: connect: connection timed out) Error: failed to connect to `host=XX user=worker database=XX_v2`: dial error (dial tcp XX:6432: connect: connection timed out) ``
(6432 = pgbouncer)

I am able to initially connect to the DB and insert records but shuts about a minute or so. Postgres is running in docker on a large node with plenty of resources. There are about 200 containers connecting to the database.

Things I have tried:

- I have tried putting a connection pooler in front of the DB which did not help.
- Collected metrics with prometheus exporter and grafana -> nothing stands out?
- Doing code reviews of application for any build up in unclosed connections

  - Any particular tips on how to inspect this deeper?
- Updated the postgres conf recommendations via https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/.

```sh
# WARNING
# this tool not being optimal
# for very high memory systems

# DB Version: 9.6
# OS Type: linux
# DB Type: web
# Total Memory (RAM): 200 GB
# CPUs num: 40
# Connections num: 2000
# Data Storage: ssd
listen_addresses = '*'

max_connections = 2000
shared_buffers = 50GB
effective_cache_size = 150GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 6553kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 40
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
```

- Does this look like a network issue?
- Where to start debugging next from here?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated in this!

Comment: What is the complete text of the error message?

Comment: @jjanes - TY for your help.  I updated the question with the specific logs.

Comment: Consistent connection timeouts generally indicate a firewall issue.  Sporadic ones probably indicate something is broken in the network.  It could just be the server is massively overloaded and in the process of swapping itself to death. Look in the system logs to see if there is indication of problems there. Having 200 containers all connecting to one database is a lot.  It won't necessarily be a problem, but if they all become active at once it could become one.

Comment: I'm seeing intermittent timeouts too, did you find the underlying issue?

Comment: @brauliobo - Ended up being application related I believe.

Comment: in my case setting `ulimit -n 1001001` to higher than the default made it work